# DB error : include(database-connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mariadb

I've Setup the php project, installed all necessary packages. I'am able to launch the website.
However, when I try logging into it(submit username and password), I get the error as "include(database-connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
I've checked the documentation and performed

1. composer install
2. php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
3. updated the .env file with correct DB credentials

Could someone help me out with further troubleshooting, I'm performing this activity for the first time.

Comment: are you manually including a `database-connection.php ` file somewhere?

Comment: No, I did a git pull from github, which includes all the files. This project is running successfully on other servers. I'am a DevOps Engineer for this project and trying replicate the same website on different servers.

Comment: well the error you're facing is something not related, is there a stack trace somewhere? can you post the output?

Comment: I'm unable to attache the screenshot here.

Comment: well can you copy and paste the output?

Comment: The Stack trace shows Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
routes/web.php:6

Comment: well as the stack trace says `routes/web.php` start checking from there, also before you do anything did you try running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: no, I will run that now